# Celery 4.1 periodic tasks error

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I am trying to setup a task to run every ten seconds.Using Celery Beat.

**I am using:**

```
 Django==1.11.3
 celery==4.1.0
 django-celery-beat==1.1.1
 django-celery-results==1.0.1
```

It is giving me the following error:

Received unregistered task of type 'operations.tasks.message'

I am new to Celery, I have tried numerous solutions and cannot seem to find a solution,would appreciate the help

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest@localhost//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Johannesburg'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'message': {
        'task': 'operations.tasks.message',
        'schedule': 10.0
    }
    }
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nodiso.settings')

app = Celery('nodiso')

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**task.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from operations import models
from .celery import periodic_task



@task
def message():
    t = models.Celerytest.objects.create(Message='Hello World')
    t.save()
```

**files structure**

```
proj-
     proj-
         __init__.py
         settings.py-
         celery.py-
     app-
         tasks.py-
```

Comment: IIRC Celery taks names are (by default) the method names, so your task is probably registered with just the name "message", rather than as "operations.tasks.message" from your config.

Comment: your file is named `task.py` (at least in the description of your problem), but you are giving this path instead `operations.tasks.message`, note the `S`. Also, you are using the decorator `@task` but it is not defined (imported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within my celery.py file I define `app` like this:

```
app = Celery(
    'your_celery_app_name',
    include=[
        'your_celery_app_name.module.task1',
        'your_celery_app_name.module.task2',
    ]
)
app.config_from_object('your_celery_app_name.celeryconfig')
```

My `celeryconfig.py` is where I define my beats and other settings (I think this would be same as your settings.py).

Below is probably not relevant - I'm not an expert with Python and how package should be put together - but from my limited understanding your tasks should be a submodule of your celery app module. Take this with pinch of salt though.

My project structure looks more like this:

```
your_celery_app_name (dir)
    setup.py (file)
    your_celery_app_name (dir)
        __init__.py (file)
        celery.py (file)
        celeryconfig.py (file)
        module (dir)
            __init__.py (importing task1 and task2 from tasks)
            tasks.py (implementing task1 and task2)
```